# AngularJS filter search not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I want to use the angular filter in my table. It was working initially when the structure of displaying table data was simple but now since I have to perform some additional task I have changed the structure of data returned from the server. I have attached pics of the structure of data I'm receiving in `$scope.tables`.

Code is straight forward where I'm iterating over `$scope.tables` and displaying table header and table body using cols and `rows` of $scope.tables respectively.

Everything else is working like sorting using $scope.sortkey and $scope.reverse. But search is not working at all. I tried different variant to put the filter at different location but no success.

```
<div ng-if="hasSearch == 'true'">
        <form class="form-inline">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label >Search</label>
                  <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
             </div>
        </form>
 </div>

 <table border="1" ng-repeat="table in tables" class="table table-hover 
       table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-sm">
      <caption class="captionAlign">Application Status</caption>
           <thead class="thead-inverse">
              <tr>
                  <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in table.cols" ng-click="sort(key,value)">{{value}}
                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey== '\''+'{'+key+'='+value+'}'+'\''" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="row in table.rows | orderBy:sortKey:reverse| filter:search" ng-if="hasPagination === 'false'"> 
                  <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in table.cols" > {{row['{'+key+'='+value+'}']}}</td> 
              </tr>
           </tbody>
    </table>
```

Is there any fundamental mistake I'm making. Any insight will be helpful.

Structure of $scope.tables : (in 3 pics)
[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate this with a plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: Maybe directives are conflicting (ng-repeat and ng-if on tr). Did you try moving the ng-if one level up, on <tbody> ?

Comment: I have never done that, I have to check how I can add everything. Is there anything you can suggest from the code provided

Comment: @ChristianBonato I didn't. I'll try it now.Conflicting may happen

Comment: @ChristianBonato No, it didn't help either. I moved one step up

Comment: Why are table.rows keys surrounded by brackets? I can see you're trying to reassign keys names, but I'm not sure Angular is happy with that.

Comment: @ChristianBonato If I don't do that , result will look like this `row['{'+key+'='+value+'}']`. So to overcome merge field issue